# custom field not working in omnipay/paypal laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed `omnipay/paypal` in laravel 5.8. I am  calling PayPal_Express. I am trying to send the custom field.In Response I am not getting the custom field back.

Here is my code

```
$this->gateway->setParameter('custom','123456');

    $response = $this->gateway->purchase([
        'amount' => 30.00,
        'transactionId' => Carbon::now()->timestamp ,
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'cancelUrl' => url('/cancelpaypal'),
        'returnUrl' => url('/successpaypal'),
        'notifyUrl' => url('/notify'),
    ])->send();
```

i am not using any data base since trying to implement the paypal first. 
thanks in advance for any help

I have tried `setParameter()`. this is setting parameters. but not coming back in response.

Comment: $this->gateway->setParameter('custom','123456'); this is ima using

Comment: fyi: "_Here is my code_" There is no code!

Comment: $this->gateway->setParameter('custom','123456');
        
        $response = $this->gateway->purchase([
            'amount' => 30.00,
            'transactionId' => Carbon::now()->timestamp ,
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'cancelUrl' => url('/cancelpaypal'),
            'returnUrl' => url('/successpaypal'),
            'notifyUrl' => url('/notify'),
        ])->send();

Comment: Please don't paste code in the comments, hard to read. I pasted/formatted that code in your question

Comment: ok actually this is my first post in stack over flow.. getting confused

Comment: Not a problem. Don't know anything about omnipay/paypal, have you tried adding that custom parameter to the array in the `$this->gateway->purchase()` method? Other than that I'm of no help here

Comment: yes i also tried this. but no luck. i can find it in the gateway object. but missing in the response object